# String text split

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, split

I have to split this:

```
string text = "John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
```

A logic must be created that will separately extract data from this record:

first name;
last name;
place of birth.

In other words, the displayed String must be edited using the method of the String class and each person's data must be extracted separately. The main method to use is to classify Strings on multiple parts.

```
string text = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";

string[] textArray = text.Split('"', ' ');
Console.WriteLine("Date: ");

foreach (string str in textArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] FirstName = textArray[i].Split(' ');                  
        string[] LastName = textArray[i].Split('.');
        string[] BirthPlace = textArray[i].Split('/');
        Console.WriteLine($"First name: {FirstName} Last Name: {LastName} BirthPlace: {BirthPlace}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a output example

Comment: This is the output - First name: System.String[] Last Name: System.String[] BirthPlace: System.String[]

Comment: I mean the output you want

Comment: And please provide *both* the desired output *and* the actual output in the question, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you were iterating your array twice.

```
   string text = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";

    string[] textArray = text.Trim().Split(" ");
    Console.WriteLine($"Date: {DateTime.Now} ");


    String[] delimiters = { ".", "/" };


    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.Length; i++)
    {
        String[] parts = textArray[i].Split(delimiters,StringSplitOptions.None);
                
        Console.WriteLine($"First name: {parts[0]} Last Name: {parts[1]} BirthPlace: {parts[2]}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @" *(?<FirstName>\w+)\.(?<LastName>\w+)/(?<BirthPlace>\w+)";
string input = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match match in m)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"First name: {match.Groups["FirstName"]} Last Name: {match.Groups["LastName"]} BirthPlace: {match.Groups["BirthPlace"]}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the split method properly. Also would be nice to structure the parsing in a Try method which handles errors also. Here's an example:

```
static bool TryParseRecord(string record, out string firstName, out string lastName, out string birthPlace)
{
    firstName = lastName = birthPlace = "";
    record = record.Trim();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(record))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // parse for birth place
    var stringSplit = record.Split('/');
    if (stringSplit.Length == 2)
    {
        record = stringSplit[0];
        birthPlace = stringSplit[1];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    // parse for names
    stringSplit = record.Split('.');
    if (stringSplit.Length == 2)
    {
        firstName = stringSplit[0];
        lastName = stringSplit[1];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(birthPlace) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName);
}
```

With this, your main would become something like:

```
static void Main()
{
    var text = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";

    var textArray = text.Split(' ');
    Console.WriteLine("Date: ");

    foreach (var entry in textArray)
    {
        if (TryParseRecord(entry, out var FirstName, out var LastName, out var BirthPlace))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"First name: {FirstName}, Last Name: {LastName}, Birth place: {BirthPlace}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by defining a class to hold the data.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string placeOfBirth)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        PlaceOfBirth = placeOfBirth;
    }
}
```

I would then define a class to do the extracting.
The original string seperates each `Person` by a space, so the first thing we need is to split on the space character. This gives an array with three strings.

```
John.Davidson/Belgrade
Michael.Barton/Krakow
Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow
```

Again we can use the `Split()` function to first split the string to get the names and the place of birth, and then to seperate the first name and the last name.

```
string[] data = personData.Split('/');
string[] names = data[0].Split('.');
```

Lastly we simple loop the array, and call the constructor for the `Person`. Combine it all in a class:

```
public class PersonDataExtractor
{
    public static List<Person> ExtractData(string text)
    {
        string[] peopleData = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var personDataList = new List<Person>();

        foreach (string personData in peopleData)
        {
            string[] data = personData.Split('/');
            string[] names = data[0].Split('.');
            string firstName = names[0];
            string lastName = names[1];
            string placeOfBirth = data[1];
            personDataList.Add(new Person(firstName, lastName, placeOfBirth));
        }

        return personDataList;
    }
}
```

This is also easy to unit test. Here with xUnit

```
public class PersonDataExtractorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void ExtractPersonData_ValidInput_ExtractsDataCorrectly()
    {
        // Arrange
        string text = "John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";

        // Act
        var personDataList = PersonDataExtractor.ExtractData(text);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(3, personDataList.Count);

        Assert.Equal("John", personDataList[0].FirstName);
        Assert.Equal("Davidson", personDataList[0].LastName);
        Assert.Equal("Belgrade", personDataList[0].PlaceOfBirth);
        
        Assert.Equal("Michael", personDataList[1].FirstName);
        Assert.Equal("Barton", personDataList[1].LastName);
        Assert.Equal("Krakow", personDataList[1].PlaceOfBirth);
        
        Assert.Equal("Ivan", personDataList[2].FirstName);
        Assert.Equal("Perkinson", personDataList[2].LastName);
        Assert.Equal("Moscow", personDataList[2].PlaceOfBirth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

we do it in python like this:

```py
text = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow"
for record in text.split(" "):
    if record != "":
        temp, city = record.split("/")
        name, surname = temp.split(".")
        print(f"First name: {name} Last Name: {surname} BirthPlace: {city}")
```

and I converted it to c#:

```c
    using System;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string text = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
            string[] textArray = text.Split('"', ' ');
            foreach (string str in textArray)
            {   
                if(str == ""){
                    continue;
                }
                string[] temp = str.Split('/');
                string city = temp[1];
                temp = temp[0].Split('.');
                string name = temp[0];
                string surname = temp[1];
                Console.WriteLine("First name: "+name+" Last Name: "+surname+" BirthPlace: "+city);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have to make in C# this.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: @MadalinaMaxim I added C# code. Sorry, I did not get that it is C# at first.